# How can I detect a disconnected client with Spring 5 Reactive WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-webflux

I managed to create a `WebSocketHandler` using the Spring 5 Reactive WebSocket support ([Chapter 23.2.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#web-reactive)). Receiving and sending all works fine. However, I can not figure out how to detect a client disconnect. When debugging a client disconnect it somewhere stops at the server side in the `HttpServerWSOperations` class (`netty.http.server` package), where it does detect a `CloseWebSocketFrame`.

Any suggestions how to deal with client disconnects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implemented a close event handler in a reactive **org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketHandler** as follows:

```
public Mono<Void> handle(final WebSocketSession session) {
    final String sessionId = session.getId();
    if(sessions.add(sessionId)) {  // add session id to set to keep a count of active sessions
        LOG.info("Starting WebSocket Session [{}]", sessionId);
        // Send the session id back to the client
        WebSocketMessage msg = session.textMessage(String.format("{\"session\":\"%s\"}", sessionId));
        // Register the outbound flux as the source of outbound messages
        final Flux<WebSocketMessage> outFlux = Flux.concat(Flux.just(msg), newMetricFlux.map(metric -> {
            LOG.info("Sending message to client [{}]: {}", sessionId, metric);
            return session.textMessage(metric);             
        }));
        // Subscribe to the inbound message flux
        session.receive().doFinally(sig -> {
            LOG.info("Terminating WebSocket Session (client side) sig: [{}], [{}]", sig.name(), sessionId);
            session.close();
            sessions.remove(sessionId);  // remove the stored session id
        }).subscribe(inMsg -> {
            LOG.info("Received inbound message from client [{}]: {}", sessionId, inMsg.getPayloadAsText());
        });
        return session.send(outFlux);
    }
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

The `newMetricFlux` field is the source of the outbound websocket messages. The trick to hooking the close event is the doFinally on the inbound message flux. When the websocket client closes, the inbound flux is terminated.

For some reason, though, there is a 1 minute delay between when the netty channel closes and the `doFinally` callback is executed. Not sure why yet.

Here's the log output for a browser client connecting and immediately closing. Note the 60 second delay between lines 3 and 4.

```
2017-08-03 11:15:41.177 DEBUG 28505 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.i.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations   : New http connection, requesting read
2017-08-03 11:15:41.294  INFO 28505 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.h.w.ws.NewMetricsWebSocketHandler      : Starting WebSocket Session [87fbe66]
2017-08-03 11:15:48.294 DEBUG 28505 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.i.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations   : CloseWebSocketFrame detected. Closing Websocket
2017-08-03 11:16:48.293  INFO 28505 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.h.w.ws.NewMetricsWebSocketHandler      : Terminating WebSocket Session (client side) sig: [ON_COMPLETE], [87fbe66]
```

***Update: October 13, 2017:***

As of Spring 5 GA, the delay mentioned above is not present and I observe my callback being invoked immediately after the client is closed. Not sure which version this was fixed in, but as I said, it's fixed in 5.0 GA.

Comment: Great! That solved it! Did not look into the delay yet.

Comment: Only one note...remember to add @EnableWebFlux on you app....otherwise will not work...

Comment: Do you have a sample project for this as much I feel like this has more to offer than most of the web flux documentation has especially these simple scenarios for a vanilla set up on web  with out using the stomp etc libs

Comment: If i want to know what is the Close Reason/Code for the websocket connection, is that possible? Because I am not seeing an option with this approach - probably I am missing something

Comment: Have not looked at the results of this myself, but the WebSocketSession has a method

Mono<CloseStatus> closeStatus()

which, via the returned Mono, will provide a CloseStatus which will indicate the reason for the session termination.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect that thanks to the  `afterConnectionClosed` method. You can even handle transport errors thanks to the method `handleTransportError`. Here is a code snippet:

```
@Component
public class YourHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourHandler .class);
    private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        logger.debug("Connected : " + session);
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) {
        try {
            //check the close status if you want...
            if (!status.equals(CloseStatus.NORMAL)) {
                session.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Cannot close session on afterConnectionClosed ", e);
        }
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) {
        logger.debug("error has occured with the following session {}", session);
        try {
            session.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Cannot close session on handleTransportError ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Receive : " + message.getPayload());      
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but your solution works for the non-reactive websocketsession and handlers. Spring 5 has a package `org.springframework.web.reactive.socket` in which the reactive variants reside. The reactive handler interface doesn't has something like `afterConnectionClosed`. So looking at your code this seems the functionality i would like to have, but can't implement. Again look at the chapter I'm referring to. NB: To enable spring reactive web replace the `spring-boot-starter-web` with `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. Or go to initializr and choose spring boot 2.0.0M2 and add Reactive Web